# Deleting data from SQLite database doesn't work in Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I'm having an Activity which handles a details Fragment for my Movie data & I want to implement **favorite** functionality. But the issue is that I can favorite only one movie at a time. Also, each time I try to add/favorite a movie, it'll show on the database that it's being saved but never being deleted on *unfavorite*.

Here's the code that I've:

**MovieDetailsActivity**

```
public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Set the content of the activity to use the activity_tv_show_details.xml layout file */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
    Bundle movieDetails = new Bundle();

    /**get the movie's Object from the parent activity**/
    Movie movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("movie");
    movieDetails.putParcelable("movie", movie);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri mCurrentMovieUri = intent.getData();
    movieDetails.putString("currentMovieUri", mCurrentMovieUri.toString());

    /* Check for pre-existing instances of fragments(here explicitly check for savedInstance)
    and then begin fragment transaction accordingly */
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MovieDetailsFragment defaultMovieFragment = new MovieDetailsFragment();
        defaultMovieFragment.setArguments(movieDetails);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerMovieDetailActivity, defaultMovieFragment)
                .commit();
    }
   }
 }
```

**MovieDetailsFragment**

```
public class MovieDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MovieDetailsBundle> {

private static final int MOVIE_DETAIL_LOADER_ID = 2;

/* Arrays for holding movie details */


Movie movie;


public MovieDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_detail, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");
    currentMovieUri = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("currentMovieUri"));

    favoriteButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mReview = new ArrayList<>();
        mVideo = new ArrayList<>();
        mCredits = new ArrayList<>();
        mMovieDetailsBundle = new MovieDetailsBundle();
    }

    if ((bundle != null)) {
        movie = getArguments().getParcelable("movie");
        movieDetailTitleTextView.setText(movie.getMovieTitle());
        ...


        String[] projection = {
                MoviesEntry._ID,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_OVERVIEW,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER_URL,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_BACKDROP_URL,
                MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING};

        // Perform a query on the provider using the ContentResolver.
        // Use the {@link MoviesEntry#CONTENT_URI} to access the pet data.
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MoviesEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the movies table
                projection,             // The columns to return for each row
                null,                   // Selection criteria
                null,                   // Selection criteria
                null);


        try {

            // Figure out the index of each column
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry._ID);
            int titleColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE);

            int releaseDateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE);
            int overviewColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_OVERVIEW);
            int posterUrlColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER_URL);
            int backdropUrlColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_BACKDROP_URL);
            int ratingColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING);

            // Iterate through all the returned rows in the cursor
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                // Use that index to extract the String or Int value of the word
                // at the current row the cursor is on.
                currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                currentTitle = cursor.getString(titleColumnIndex);
                currentReleaseDate = cursor.getString(releaseDateColumnIndex);
                currentOverview = cursor.getString(overviewColumnIndex);
                currentposterUrl = cursor.getString(posterUrlColumnIndex);
                currentBackdropUrl = cursor.getString(backdropUrlColumnIndex);
                currentRatings = cursor.getFloat(ratingColumnIndex);
            }
        } finally {
            // Always close the cursor when you're done reading from it. This releases all its
            // resources and makes it invalid.
            cursor.close();
        }

        if (currentTitle!=null) {
            //currentTitle = movie.getMovieTitle();
            if (currentTitle.equals(movie.getMovieTitle())) {
                favoriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.starred);
                favorite = true;
            }
        }else{
            favoriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unstarred);
            favorite = false;
        }
        /*setting the ratingbar from @link: https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar*/
        SimpleRatingBar simpleRatingBar = (SimpleRatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movieRatingInsideMovieDetailsFragment);
        simpleRatingBar.setRating((float) (movie.getMovieVoteAverage()) / 2);
        favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (favorite) {
                    // Only perform the delete if this is an existing movie.
                    if (currentMovieUri != null) {

                        // Call the ContentResolver to delete the movie at the given content URI.
                        // Pass in null for the selection and selection args because the mCurrentPetUri
                        // content URI already identifies the movie that we want.
                        int rowsDeleted = getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(currentMovieUri, null, null);

                        // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the delete was successful.
                        if (rowsDeleted == 0) {
                            // If no rows were deleted, then there was an error with the delete.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.delete_movie_failed),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Otherwise, the delete was successful and we can display a toast.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.delete_movie_successful),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    favoriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unstarred);

                } else {
                    // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
                    // and movie attributes from the editor are the values.
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE, movie.getMovieTitle());
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE, movie.getMovieReleaseDate());
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_OVERVIEW, movie.getMovieOverview());
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER_URL, movie.getMoviePosterPath());
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_BACKDROP_URL, movie.getMovieBackdropPath());
                    values.put(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING, movie.getMovieVoteAverage() / 2);

                    // Insert a new movie into the provider, returning the content URI for the new movie.
                    Uri newUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MoviesEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

                    // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the insertion was successful
                    if (newUri == null) {
                        // If the new content URI is null, then there was an error with insertion.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.insert_movie_failed),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.insert_movie_successful),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    favoriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.starred);
                }

                favorite = !favorite;
            }
        });

        ...
@Override
public Loader<MovieDetailsBundle> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse((UrlsAndConstants.MovieDetailQuery.DEFAULT_URL) + movie.getMovieId());
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(API_KEY_PARAM, API_KEY_PARAM_VALUE);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(APPEND_TO_RESPONSE, VIDEOS_AND_REVIEWS_AND_CREDITS);
    return new DetailsMovieLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uriBuilder.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<MovieDetailsBundle> loader, )
  ...
}

public void updateDurationTextView(MovieDetailsBundle movieDetailsBundle) {

    ...
    movieRunTimeDuration.setText(mMovieDurationString);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<MovieDetailsBundle> loader) {
  }
}
```

**ContentProvider**

```
public class MovieProvider extends ContentProvider {
/**
 * URI matcher code for the content URI for the movies table
 */

private static final int MOVIES = 100;

/**
 * URI matcher code for the content URI for a single movie in the movie table
 */
private static final int MOVIE_ID = 200;

/**
 * UriMatcher object to match a content URI to a corresponding code.
 * The input passed into the constructor represents the code to return for the root URI.
 * It's common to use NO_MATCH as the input for this case.
 */
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

// Static initializer. This is run the first time anything is called from this class.
static {
    // The calls to addURI() go here, for all of the content URI patterns that the provider
    // should recognize. All paths added to the UriMatcher have a corresponding code to return
    // when a match is found.

    // The content URI of the form "content://com.example.android.movie/movie" will map to the
    // integer code {@link #MOVIES}. This URI is used to provide access to MULTIPLE rows
    // of the movie table.
    sUriMatcher.addURI(MovieContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, MovieContract.PATH_MOVIES, MOVIES);

    // The content URI of the form "content://com.example.android.movie/movie/#" will map to the
    // integer code {@link #MOVIES}. This URI is used to provide access to ONE single row
    // of the movie table.
    //
    // In this case, the "#" wildcard is used where "#" can be substituted for an integer.
    // For example, "content://com.example.android.movie/movie/3" matches, but
    // "content://com.example.android.movie/movie" (without a number at the end) doesn't match.
    sUriMatcher.addURI(MovieContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, MovieContract.PATH_MOVIES + "/#", MOVIE_ID);
}


/**
 * Database helper object
 */
private MovieDbHelper mDbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDbHelper = new MovieDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    // Get readable database
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // This cursor will hold the result of the query
    Cursor cursor;

    // Figure out if the URI matcher can match the URI to a specific code
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (match) {
        case MOVIES:
            // For the MOVIES code, query the movie table directly with the given
            // projection, selection, selection arguments, and sort order. The cursor
            // could contain multiple rows of the movie table.
            cursor = database.query(MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case MOVIE_ID:
            // For the MOVIE_ID code, extract out the ID from the URI.
            // For an example URI such as "content://com.example.android.movie/movie/3",
            // the selection will be "_id=?" and the selection argument will be a
            // String array containing the actual ID of 3 in this case.
            //
            // For every "?" in the selection, we need to have an element in the selection
            // arguments that will fill in the "?". Since we have 1 question mark in the
            // selection, we have 1 String in the selection arguments' String array.
            selection = MoviesEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};

            // This will perform a query on the movie table where the _id equals 3 to return a
            // Cursor containing that row of the table.
            cursor = database.query(MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    // Set notification URI on the Cursor,
    // so we know what content URI the Cursor was created for.
    // If the data at this URI changes, then we know we need to update the Cursor.
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    // Return the cursor
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case MOVIES:
            return insertMovie(uri, contentValues);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for " + uri);
    }
}


/**
 * Insert a movie into the database with the given content values. Return the new content URI
 * for that specific row in the database.
 */
private Uri insertMovie(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
   // Log.v("my_tag", "Received Uri to be matched insert is :"+uri.toString());
    Log.i("my_tag", "Received Uri to be matched insert is :"+uri.toString());
    // Check that the product name is not null
    String title = values.getAsString(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE);
    if (title == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires a name");
    }

    // Check that the product name is not null
    String releaseDate = values.getAsString(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE);
    if (releaseDate == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires a detail");
    }

    // If the price is provided, check that it's greater than or equal to 0
    String overview = values.getAsString(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_OVERVIEW);
    if (overview == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires valid price");
    }

    String posterUrl = values.getAsString(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER_URL);
    if (posterUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires valid quantity");
    }
    String backdropUrl = values.getAsString(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_BACKDROP_URL);
    if (backdropUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires valid quantity");
    }
    Integer ratings = values.getAsInteger(MoviesEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING);
    if (ratings != null && ratings < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product requires valid quantity");
    }

    // Get writeable database
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Insert the new product with the given values
    long id = database.insert(MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    Log.i("my_tag", "values is :"+values.toString());
   // Log.e("my_tag", "values is :"+values.toString());
   // Log.v("my_tag", "values is :"+values.toString());
    if (id == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    // Notify all listeners that the data has changed for the product content URI
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    // Return the new URI with the ID (of the newly inserted row) appended at the end
    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    // Get writeable database
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Track the number of rows that were deleted
    int rowsDeleted;

    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);


        case MOVIES:
            // Delete all rows that match the selection and selection args
            rowsDeleted = database.delete(MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case MOVIE_ID:
            // Delete a single row given by the ID in the URI
            selection = MoviesEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            Log.i("my_tag", "selection is :"+selection);
         //   Log.e("my_tag", "selection is :"+selection);
         //   Log.v("my_tag", "selection is :"+selection);
            Log.i("my_tag", "selectionArgs is :"+selectionArgs[0]);
          //  Log.e("my_tag", "selectionArgs is :"+selectionArgs[0]);
          //  Log.v("my_tag", "selectionArgs is :"+selectionArgs[0]);
            rowsDeleted = database.delete(MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deletion is not supported for " + uri);
    }

    // If 1 or more rows were deleted, then notify all listeners that the data at the
    // given URI has changed
    if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    // Return the number of rows deleted
    return rowsDeleted;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
   ...
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case MOVIES:
            return MoviesEntry.CONTENT_LIST_TYPE;
        case MOVIE_ID:
            return MoviesEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown URI " + uri + " with match " + match);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't dump your entire classes please, only copy the segments related to the question.

Comment: @Ryan I've now edited the thread. Can you please look into it now?

Comment: Is `rowsDeleted` == 0 all the time?

Comment: Looks like you implement own content provider. Probably delete method works incorrectly. Can you show a content provider?

Comment: @MaximTulupov I've now edited my post with ContentProvider code.

Comment: @Ryan putting Log statement, it says that 1 item deleted but when I see the database file (on my machine) then I can still see those data

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE. My suggestion is that you move the code that interacts with the movie in a totally separate class, then use it from a Fragment or Activity or whatever you wish. This way data manipulation code is indepdendent from GUI and always behaves the same way.

Comment: @m0skit0 I'll certainly do that, but can you please let me know if something wrong you find here. I'd really appreciate that as I'm struggling with it for almost 10 days.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to read all that code. I think if you did it from the beginning, you wouldn't be struggling for 10 days, so do it now to avoid strugglinh for other 10 days :)

Comment: Thanks, @m0skit0 I'll do it right away.